# Maximizer is infinity; what's the proper notation?

Tags: notation, maxima-minima

What notation is appropriate for the following statement? 
\begin{align}
\arg\max_{x \in \mathbb R} x &= \infty\\
& \to \infty\\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} x
\end{align}

Comment: I would say $\arg\max_{x \in \Bbb{R}} x = \emptyset$, since $\infty \notin \Bbb{R}$, but that's just me. Maybe $\arg\max_{x \in [-\infty, \infty]} x = \infty$?

Comment: The problem here is that $\infty\not\in\Bbb R$